# Mercurial Hg and multiple users on a single repo

Tags: mercurial

User A commited and pushed File A to the repo incrementing the version to 10. In the meantime, User B commited File B and started pushing out to the repo.  User B got a message about 'pushing changes will create a new head, merge when possible'.  User B did not know what to do at that time.

User B is me.  What should I have done?  I just freaked out and re-cloned the repo.  My local copy was at version 9 at the time of my commit.  So I wanted to update mine to 10 and then push mine out.

I am using Mercurial Hg.

Thanks.

Comment: Read [HgInit](http://hginit.com). **:)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pull changes and merge them (In details you can read about it here: http://hginit.com/04.html)

Also - don't refer to revision number, it makes sense only for single repository. As long as you have several copies of the one - the better is to refer to the commit by its hash.